# PHP - Convert String to Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I'm struggling with this..

I have a string like this.

`$test2 = "AB:001,003;AC:001,003,004,005,008;AD:002,003,004,007,008,009";`

It's two letters : 3 digits, (this can repeat)  ;

This string will have multiple 2 letter prefixes, and the amount of 3 digit entries will vary.

I need to be able to find a match between a 2 letter prefix and an associated 3 digits number.

EG: Does AD003 exist in the string ? I know 003 appears mulitple times but I'd want to find just AD003, or another match I query for.

I thought converting the string to individual arrays named after the 2 letter prefixes would be the way to go..

```
$AB = array('001','003');
$AC = array('001','003','004',008);
$AD = array('002','003','004','007','008','009');
```

I've got as far as exploding it on the `;` and then the `:`

```
$parts =  explode(";",$test2) ;
foreach ($parts as $value) {
    $a[] = explode(":", $value);
}
print_r ( $a );
```

This results in  :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AB
            [1] => 001,002,003
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => AC
            [1] => 001,003,004,005
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => AD
            [1] => 002,003,004
        )

)
```

But I don't know how to take it further than that.

I want to be able to search the arrays for specific matches:

```
if (in_array("003", $AD)) { 
    echo "Match";
}
```

If there is an easier way than converting to array to find AD003 in the string, then I'm happy to try that.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or simply you can use preg_match to check in string

```
$string = "AB:001,003;AC:001,003,004,005,008;AD:002,003,004,007,008,009";

if( preg_match('/AD:([0-9,]+)?003/',$string)){
//Your code here
}
```

Comment: this seems the best solution for the query you want to search for

Comment: Thanks this seems the simplest solution. is there any problem doing this `if( ! preg_match('/AD:([0-9,]+)?003/',$string)){` ?

Thanks

Comment: @Rocket Definitely no

Comment: ? No there is no issue ? or no don't do it ? :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the first array value as key:

```
$parts = explode(":", $value);
$key = array_shift($parts);
$a[$key] = $parts;
```

Then you can do:

```
if(isset($a['AD']) && in_array("003", $a['AD']))
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$test2 = "AB:001,003;AC:001,003,004,005,008;AD:002,003,004,007,008,009";

$parts = explode( ';', $test2 );
foreach( $parts as $value ) {
    list( $key, $digits ) = explode( ':', $value );
    $a[$key] = explode( ',', $digits );
}

print_r( $a );

if( !empty( $a['AB'] ) && in_array( '003', $a['AB'] ) ) {
    echo "Yep, it's there.";
}
```

Here's the result:

```
Array
(
    [AB] => Array
        (
            [0] => 001
            [1] => 003
        )

    [AC] => Array
        (
            [0] => 001
            [1] => 003
            [2] => 004
            [3] => 005
            [4] => 008
        )

    [AD] => Array
        (
            [0] => 002
            [1] => 003
            [2] => 004
            [3] => 007
            [4] => 008
            [5] => 009
        )

)
Yep, it's there.
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php

$test2 = "AB:001,003;AC:001,003,004,005,008;AD:002,003,004,007,008,009";

$final = array();
$parts =  explode(";",$test2) ;
foreach ($parts as $value) {

    $a = explode(":", $value);
    foreach(explode(",", $a[1])as $val)
    {
       $final[$a[0].$val] =  $val;     
    }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($final);
```

Result will be

```
Array
(
    [AB001] => 001
    [AB003] => 003
    [AC001] => 001
    [AC003] => 003
    [AC004] => 004
    [AC005] => 005
    [AC008] => 008
    [AD002] => 002
    [AD003] => 003
    [AD004] => 004
    [AD007] => 007
    [AD008] => 008
    [AD009] => 009
)
```

you can check if the value `AB001` exists by using `array_key_exists('AB001',$array);`

Comment: the other 2nd best solutions other than regex, than can be used for searching your query

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
// Example 1
$apple = "apple1 apple2 apple3 apple4 apple5 apple6";
$apples = explode(" ", $apple);
echo $apples[0]; // apple1
echo $apples[1]; // apple2...........

?>
```